# Embedding Applet in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, applet, classname

So I'm learning how to embed an applet into a jsp page. But the thing is, when I run the index.jsp, there's always an error. The error says that the class for the applet is missing, and I don't know how to fix that. I put the full class name of the applet in the index.jsp, and the jar file for the applet was made. Here is the code for the applet and jsp.

```
    package HelloApplet;

    import java.applet.Applet;
    import java.awt.Graphics;

    public class HelloApplet extends Applet {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
             g.drawString("Hello applet!", 50, 25);
        }//end paint

    }//end class

    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <br>
            <applet code="HelloApplet.HelloApplet" archive="HelloApplet.jar" width="600" height="480"/>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can the code attributte be a .jar ? Everything in the right directory?

Try something like this:

```
<applet code="HelloApplet.class" name="HelloApplet" archive="HelloApplet.jar"
    width=300 height=300>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="ffffff">
    <param name="fontcolor" value="000000">
    Your browser is not Java enabled.
</applet>
```

For more help, use this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp)